# Cuales son los parámetros correctos en ViewModelProvider?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-viewmodel

Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo a realizar aplicaciones en AndroidStudio 4.0.1 y decidí guiarme por un [CodeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..index#14) de google. El problema radica en que cuando tengo que instanciar un ViewModelProvider me doy cuenta que en el codeLab solo usa el parámetro (this)

```
new ViewModelProvider(this).get(VWMCliente.class);
```

y en la implementacion mia pide otro parámetro adicional(this, factory)

```
new ViewModelProvider(this, ¿facactory?).get(VWMCliente.class);
```

y no se que es ese factory. el Error se encuentra en el MainActivity, no tengo idea de como solucionar el error, ya e googleado sin obtener resultados, esta es mi ultima alternativa, gracias de antemano

para entrar en contexto comparto el codigo que creo relevante:
Trato de implementar Room para la persistencia de datos.

Codigo del ViewModel

```java
public class VWMCliente extends AndroidViewModel {

        /** A T R I B U T O S **/
    private REPClientes iREPClientes;
    private LiveData<List<ENTClientes>> iListaOrdenadaClientes;

    /** C O N S T R I C T O R **/
    public VWMCliente(Application application) {   /* <-> Así esta en el Tutorial, sin @NonNull*/
    //public VWMCliente(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        iREPClientes           = new REPClientes(application);
        iListaOrdenadaClientes = iREPClientes.getAllClientes();
    }

    public LiveData<List<ENTClientes>> getiListaOrdenadaClientes() {
        return iListaOrdenadaClientes;
    }

    public void InsertanCliente(ENTClientes iENTClientes){
        iREPClientes.InsertanCliente(iENTClientes);
    }
}
```

Codigo del Adaptador para el RecyclerView:

```java
public class ADPRCVListaClientes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ADPRCVListaClientes.VisorClientes> {

    // S U B C L A S E
    public class VisorClientes extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView cliente_item_view;

        public VisorClientes(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cliente_item_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_txv_cliente);
        }
    }

    private final LayoutInflater iInflador;
    private List<ENTClientes> iLISTENTClientes;

    // C O N D S T R U C T O R   DE ADPRVWListaClientes clase principal
    public ADPRCVListaClientes(Context context) {
        iInflador = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setENTClientes(List<ENTClientes> pLISTENTClientes){
        iLISTENTClientes = pLISTENTClientes;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VisorClientes onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup padre, int viewType) {
        View itemView = iInflador.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, padre, false);
        return new VisorClientes(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VisorClientes titular, int position) {
        if(iLISTENTClientes != null) {
            ENTClientes iENTClientes_Actual = iLISTENTClientes.get(position);
            titular.cliente_item_view.setText(iENTClientes_Actual.getCliente_nombre());
        } else {
            titular.cliente_item_view.setText("No hay clientes");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(iLISTENTClientes != null){
            return iLISTENTClientes.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Esta en una Actividad con un Formulario, investigando me doy cuenta que seria mejor un fragment pero lo corregire despues...

```java
public class FormularioPersona extends AppCompatActivity {

    /* variables miembros **********/
    public static final String EXTRA_REPLY = "com.example.android.clienteslistsql.REPLY";

    /* widgets *******************/
    private EditText wEmail, wNombre;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulario_persona);

        this.wEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inPersonaEmail);
        this.wNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inPersonaNombre);
    }

    // Evento del boton agregar Nuevo Usuario
    public void AgregarCliente(){
        final Button iButtonAgregarCliente = findViewById(R.id.id_btn_agregar_cliente);
        iButtonAgregarCliente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent iIntencionRespueste = new Intent();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(wEmail.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(wNombre.getText())){
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, iIntencionRespueste);
                } else {
                    String email  = wEmail.getText().toString();
                    String nombre = wNombre.getText().toString();
                    //ArrayList<String> DatosCliente = new ArrayList();
                    //DatosCliente.add(email);
                    //DatosCliente.add(nombre);
                    //iIntencionRespueste.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, DatosCliente);
                    iIntencionRespueste.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, email);
                    iIntencionRespueste.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, nombre);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, iIntencionRespueste);
                }
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

y por ultimo el mainActivity, aqui me sale el error, donde estan los ?????

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ADPRCVListaClientes iADPRCVListaClientes;
    private VWMCliente iVWMCliente;
    public static final int NEW_CLIENTE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      
        RecyclerView iRecyclerView =findViewById(R.id.id_recyclerview);
        this.iADPRCVListaClientes = new ADPRCVListaClientes(this);
        iRecyclerView.setAdapter(iADPRCVListaClientes);
        iRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        iVWMCliente = new ViewModelProvider(this, "???????").get(VWMCliente.class);
        //iVWMCliente = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(VWMCliente.class);
        iVWMCliente.getiListaOrdenadaClientes().observe(this, new Observer<List<ENTClientes>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<ENTClientes> entClientes) {
                iADPRCVListaClientes.setENTClientes(entClientes);
            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton FAB = findViewById(R.id.id_fab);
        FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FormularioPersona.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_CLIENTE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int codigo_solicitud, int codigo_resultado, Intent datos){
        super.onActivityResult(codigo_solicitud,codigo_resultado,datos);

        if(codigo_solicitud == NEW_CLIENTE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && codigo_resultado == RESULT_OK) {
            ENTClientes iENTClientes = new (datos.getStringExtra(FormularioPersona.EXTRA_REPLY)
                                           ,datos.getStringExtra(FormularioPersona.EXTRA_REPLY));
        iVWMCliente.InsertanCliente(iENTClientes);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                     ,"No se puede guardar un clinete sin datos"
                     , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

La solución era bastante cenicilla, solo era cuestiona de instalar las dependencias correctas.

```graddle
 dependencies {
        def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
        def arch_version = "2.1.0"

        // ViewModel
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
        // LiveData
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
        // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"

        // Saved state module for ViewModel
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

        // Annotation processor
        annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
        // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

        // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"

        // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"

        // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version"

        // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
        testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"
    }
```